# E-mail ArcGIS Online GeoForm submissions

Tags: arcgis-online

I have made a Geoform for folks to report incidences; however, it's useless unless someone is notified via e-mail that an incident has been reported on the map.  Does anyone know how to link the submit button to an e-mail address in addition to it's regular function?  I opened up the code but I'm not totally sure what I'm looking at.

Suggestions or is there another way to accomplish the same end goal?

Comment: Did you find a solution? There was a temporally solution via mandrill but this doesn't work anymore

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/82692)